# CSS Absolute Positioning Troubleshooting

Tags: css, html, positioning, absolute

Divs on for my site:
Header
Banner (inside the banner div: is another div call innerbanner )
Main Content
Second Content
FooterWrap

I have several divs tags on a site I'm trying to develop, and 2 of the div tags I'm using an absolute position ( 1 for Banner and the 2nd one for the Footer), however when I use the absolute positioning for the banner it pushing my main content div upward making it invisible, but my footer doesn't have that problem. Can you assist me?

Comment: Please code or jsfiddle.net

Comment: Use `jsfiddle.net` for that

Answer (score 3):

Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set a div absolute position make sure that the div which contains it has a relative position so it won't get out of the box and disorder the elements, try this for example:
html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
width:75%;
height:500px;
border:1px black solid;
position: relative;
}
.box1{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.box2{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid green;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahmedskaya/DZ2DF/

Answer (score 0):

Please check by defining some height to your parent div of absolute positioned (banner) div in css. This might be the reason of content div pushing upward. Since parent of absolute positioned div don't draw height automatically or by absolute positioned content, and collapsed to its minimum height.

So you might need to define certain height of your parent div in your css in order to make it cover the height area of your absolute positioned div.

Also since your content div would (probably) have normal content (not positioned absolutely) it would be drawing height like a normal div with them. And so footer div couldn't push upside beyond its height.

This should fix your issue.